# I have an Archos 55 Platinum. How do I turn off vibrate when I'm typing?

Tags: settings

I've turned 'vibrate' off in a couple of places, but it still vibrates when I'm typing an sms message. It's really frustrating.

Comment: which keyboard you are using? keyboard settings have an option to disable vibrate.

Answer (score 1):

By default, pressing the touchscreen creates a vibration. This functionality is available in two parts: general interface and virtual keyboard. To completely remove vibrations of this type the option must be deactivated in both sections in the Settings app.

From **Settings** > **Sound** , **uncheck Vibrate on touch.**

From **Settings** > **Language & Input**, in the section **Keyboard & input methods**, press the **settings button** next to Google Keyboard (or the 3rd party keyboard that you are using) and **uncheck Vibrate on keypress.**

Information available on: [Archos FAQ Home](http://faq.archos.com/index.php?action=artikel&cat=127&id=291&artlang=en)